# Log4cxx << operator causes access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, log4cxx

I have a dll project in VS2008 which causes my application to throw access violation. I debugged and found that in Log4cxx line, `LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, myMessage << doubleA << double B);`  the operator << is causing an issue. This is the case with all logger levels. I would like to make this work by overriding the << operator. But it seems harder than said. I looked this up in StackOverflow and what I tried till now:

I tried overriding it in the `Log4cxx` namespace:

```
namespace log4cxx { namespace helpers {
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const double& a);
} }
```

This doesn't compile:

```
more than one operator "<<" matches these operands:
            function "log4cxx::helpers::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const double &a)"
            function "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::operator<<(double _Val) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
            operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << const double
```

I tried it overriding in Std namespace (I know this is not recommended):

```
namespace std {
   ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const double& a);
}
```

This throws:

```
more than one operator "<<" matches these operands:
            function "std::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const double &a)"
            function "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::operator<<(double _Val) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
            operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << const double
```

Any idea how can I overload the operator properly and make it work??

One more thing I tried is: I tried to build the message string before it goes to the logger line.
`string myMessage = "myMessage" + double A + doubleB;` and then using this string as `LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, myMessage);` This does nothing. Got the same access violation. And I tried...

```
std::ostringstream os;
    os << "myMessage here << doubleX<< ", valuey=" << doubleY;
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, os.str());
```

Got the same access violation here too. I managed to build the `log4cxx` with VS2008 too, thought this might be the issue as I had been using the one built with VS2005.

Can you please help here? What else can I do to make this work?

Comment: Okay. It was a monumental task!! But I managed to re-build Log4cxx binaries with VS2008 and now I am able to run the code without any changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

std already has an overload for double, you cannot introduce another one. What you can do is overload it in a class.